# IndexOutOfRangeException while trying to select on database by C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, unity-game-engine

sorry if this sounds noobish.
I'm trying to make a Quiz game on Unity by using C# and a database in SQL Server.
In this part, i'm trying to show the highest score so, i did a code to select the max in database:

```
  public bool BuscarScoreFinal1()
    {
        SqlDataReader dataReader = null;

        if (RunQuery(string.Format("SELECT MAX (PlayerScore1) FROM ScoreQuiz1", tableScoreQuiz1), ref dataReader))
        {
            while (dataReader.Read())
            {
                id1 = dataReader.GetInt32(dataReader.GetOrdinal("ID"));
                PlayerName1 = dataReader.GetString(dataReader.GetOrdinal("PlayerName1"));
                PlayerScore1 = dataReader.GetInt32(dataReader.GetOrdinal("PlayerScore1"));

                break;
            }
        }

        if (dataReader != null) dataReader.Close();

        return true;
    }
```

Then, i try to print the data in a UI text in this script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class UpdateScore : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GameObject Question3Display;
    public Text yourText;
    public bool Buscardados13;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        Buscardados13 = GameObject.Find("DatabaseConnection").GetComponent<DatabaseInterface>().Connect() == true;
        Buscardados13 = GameObject.Find("DatabaseConnection").GetComponent<DatabaseInterface>().BuscarScoreFinal1() == true;
        yourText.text = Question3Display.GetComponent<DatabaseInterface>().PlayerScore1.ToString();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }
}
```

And it gives me this error:

> IndexOutOfRangeException: ID
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.BasicFieldNameLookup.GetOrdinal (System.String fieldName) (at <8012ff544f1c4cb384c200861f770215>:0)
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetOrdinal (System.String name) (at <8012ff544f1c4cb384c200861f770215>:0)
>   DatabaseInterface.BuscarScoreFinal1 () (at Assets/Scripts/DatabaseInterface.cs:621)
>   UpdateScore.Start () (at Assets/Scripts/UpdateScore.cs:17)

I think this error is not a problem of connection of selecting the wrong table because, if i try a different query (for example, just a simple select) it works without errors.
I don't think i wrote the query bad because it works in SQL Server.
Here's the table i'm trying to access;

[Here's a screenshot of the table i'm using](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TX7ZT.png)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can only speculate -- because you don't show data -- but I'm pretty sure you want:

```
SELECT TOP (1) Id, PlayerName1, PlayerScore1
FROM ScoreQuiz1
ORDER BY PlayerScore1 DESC;
```

You can't really access columns that aren't included in the `SELECT`.

Answer (score 0):

I think probably because your query is like

```
SELECT MAX (PlayerScore1) FROM ScoreQuiz1
```

But you are trying to access other columns like `ID, PlayerName1 and PlayerScore1`

So, maybe try something like

```
SELECT ID, PlayerName1, PlayerScore1
FROM ScoreQuiz1 
ORDER BY PlayerScore1 DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Hope this helps! Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

In addition, the DataReader.Read method obtains a row from the query results and then you can access each **column of the returned row** by passing the name or ordinal number of the column to the DataReader. Docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/retrieving-data-)